# Checkbox won't retrieve value in that row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my table, I have multiple rows, and all rows have a checkbox, I am trying to retrieve the VORD5 value on the row that the checkbox has been selected:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name=review]').change(function() {
    if ($('input[name=review]').is(':checked')) {
      var row = $(this).closest("tr");
      var ordNum = row.find(".VORD5a").text();

      console.log(ordNum);

      jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'B2BORD060.PGM',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          task: 'saveReview',
          VORD5a: ordNum.val(),
          Checked: 'Yes'
        },
      })

    } else {
      alert('Not checked');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr class="altcol1">
    <input type="hidden" name="VORD5a" value="02704953" />
    <input type="hidden" name="VLINE5a" value="0001" />
    <td class="text" class="VORD5">2704953</td>
    <td class="text num">1</td>
    <td class="text num">20180417</td>
    <td class="text num">52411</td>
    <td class="text"> <input type="checkbox" name="review" value="yes" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the above jquery, I am trying to retrieve the VORD5 value in the `ordNum` var, currently retrieving a blank value, any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem comes from the selector in the following line :

```
var ordNum = row.find(".VORD5a").text();
```

You're trying to select with class attribute `.VORD5a` when there's no class `VORD5a` in your document.

You need to use the `name` attribute as selector instead, like :

```
var ordNum = row.find("input[name='VORD5a']");
```

**NOTE :** You need also to remove the `.text()` else you're storing an empty string in `ordNum` since the input has no text, then you can't use `.val()` on a string when you type :

```
VORD5a: ordNum.val(),
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name=review]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

      var row = $(this).closest("tr");
      var ordNum = row.find("input[name='VORD5a']");

      console.log(ordNum.val());

      jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'B2BORD060.PGM',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          task: 'saveReview',
          VORD5a: ordNum.val(),
          Checked: 'Yes'
        },
      })

    } else {
      alert('Not checked');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="altcol1">
    <input type="hidden" name="VORD5a" value="27049511" />
    <input type="hidden" name="VLINE5a" value="0001" />
    <td class="text" class="VORD5">27049511</td>
    <td class="text num">1</td>
    <td class="text num">20180417</td>
    <td class="text num">52411</td>
    <td class="text"> <input type="checkbox" name="review" value="yes" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="altcol2">
    <input type="hidden" name="VORD5a" value="27049522" />
    <input type="hidden" name="VLINE5a" value="0002" />
    <td class="text" class="VORD5">27049522</td>
    <td class="text num">2</td>
    <td class="text num">20180417</td>
    <td class="text num">52411</td>
    <td class="text"> <input type="checkbox" name="review" value="yes" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="altcol3">
    <input type="hidden" name="VORD5a" value="27049533" />
    <input type="hidden" name="VLINE5a" value="0003" />
    <td class="text" class="VORD5">27049533</td>
    <td class="text num">3</td>
    <td class="text num">20180417</td>
    <td class="text num">52411</td>
    <td class="text"> <input type="checkbox" name="review" value="yes" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Congratulations you've earned the **[Vote up privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)**, consider to use it (y)

Comment: Found a new issue here, I think it is finding any check box on the page and is always defaulting to checked .ischecked

 $(document).ready(function() {           
$('input[name=review]').change(function(){
if($('input[name=review]').is(':checked')){

I think here I also need to specify which row I am selecting, any ideas?Thanks

Comment: Sorry that format above was terrible, I can add it to the original question

Comment: Check now the updated snippet in my post using `if ($(this).is(':checked')) {`

Answer (score 1):

In your Javascript, you are trying to find val() on a string object. 'ordNum'  is string not object. Use below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name=review]').change(function() {
    if ($('input[name=review]').is(':checked')) {


      var row = $(this).closest("tr");
      var ordNum = row.find("input[name='VORD5a']").val();
      alert(ordNum);
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'B2BORD060.PGM',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          task: 'saveReview',
          VORD5a: ordNum,
          Checked: 'Yes'
        },
      })

    } else {
      alert('Not checked');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table border="1">
  <tr class="altcol1">
    <input type="hidden" name="VORD5a" value="02704953" />
    <input type="hidden" name="VLINE5a" value="0001" />
    <td class="text" class="VORD5">2704953</td>
    <td class="text num">1</td>
    <td class="text num">20180417</td>
    <td class="text num">52411</td>
    <td class="text"> <input type="checkbox" name="review" value="yes" /></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope this will work happy coding :) check the commented line

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('input[name=review]').change(function(){
if($('input[name=review]').is(':checked')){


    var row = $(this).closest("tr"); 
//var ordNum = row.find(".VORD5a").text();
var ordNum  = row.find("input[name='VORD5a']").val()
    console.log(ordNum);
    jQuery.ajax(
        {
            url: 'B2BORD060.PGM', 
            type: 'POST',
            data: {task: 'saveReview', VORD5a: ordNum , Checked: 'Yes' },             
        })

} else {
    alert('Not checked');
}
});
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
     <tr class="altcol1"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="VORD5a" value="02704953" />
  <input type="hidden" name="VLINE5a" value="0001"/>
  <td class="text" class="VORD5">2704953</td>
  <td class="text num">1</td>
  <td class="text num">20180417</td>
  <td class="text num">52411</td>
  <td class="text"> <input type="checkbox" name="review" value="yes" /></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Happy coding :) brother

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `value` of input base on name `attribute` then use like this :-

```
<input type="hidden" name="VORD5a" value="02704953" />
var ordNum = row.find('input[name="VORD5a"]');
ordNum.val();
```